# Sum of (non-centered) Subgaussian Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, distribution-tails

If we have a finite sum of independent subgaussian (or subexponential) random variables which are not mean zero, i.e. random variables $(X_i)_{i=1, \dots, N}$ such that $\forall i=1, \dots, N$
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_i \geq t) \leq 2 \exp{\left(\frac{-t^2}{C^2}\right)} $$
for some $C > 0$, do we know that the sum is again subgaussian (or subexponential)? I know this is the case when they are centered, since we can then consider the moment-generating functions, but does this extend to the more general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first show this for $n = 2.$

We have, by expanding the square and Cauchy-Schwarz, that$$ \mathbb{E}[\exp( (X_1 + X_2)^2/K^2)] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(X_1^2+X_2^2/K^2) \cdot \exp(2 X_1X_2/K^2)] \\ \le\mathbb{E}[\exp(2X_1^2/K^2) \cdot \exp(2X_2^2/K^2)]^{1/2} \cdot \mathbb{E}[\exp(4X_1X_2/K^2)]^{1/2}.$$

But $2X_1X_2\le X_1^2 + X_2^2,$ so using independence, $$ \mathbb{E}[\exp( (X_1 +X_2)^2/K^2] \le \mathbb{E}[\exp(2X_1^2/K^2)] \mathbb{E}[\exp(2X_2^2/K^2)].$$ Now, if $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X^2/K^2)] \le 2,$ then $\mathbb{E}[\exp(2X^2/4K^2)] \le \sqrt{2}$ by using Jensen's inequality for the concave maps $u \mapsto \sqrt{u}$. This shows that $\|X_1 + X_2\|_{\psi_2} \le 2\max(\|X_1\|_{\psi_2}, \|X_2\|_{\psi_2}).$ You can use this in pairs, and iterate to show that $\|\sum X_i\| \le C n \max (\|X_i\|_{\psi_2}).$ It should probably be possible to improve this to something like $C\sum\|X_i\|_{\psi_2},$ <s>not sure right now</s> (see below).

---

Alternatively: using the fact that $\|\mathbb{E}[X]\|_{\psi_2} \le C \|X\|_{\psi_2},$ and the norm property, we have $$ \left\| \sum X_i \right\|_{\psi_2} \le \left\| \sum (X_i - \mathbb{E}[X_i])\right\|_{\psi_2} + \left\| \sum \mathbb{E}[X_i]\right\|_{\psi_2}\\ \le \left\| \sum (X_i - \mathbb{E}[X_i])\right\|_{\psi_2} + \sum_i \|\mathbb{E}[X_i]\|_{\psi_2} \\ \le \left\| \sum (X_i - \mathbb{E}[X_i])\right\|_{\psi_2} + C \sum \|X_i\|_{\psi_2}.$$ Using the fact that for centred independent random variables, the square of the subGaussian norm of their sum is bounded up to constants by the sum of the squares of their subGaussian norms, we get $$ \left\| \sum X_i \right\|_{\psi_2} \le \sqrt{C \sum \|X_i\|_{\psi_2}^2} +  C' \sum \|X_i\|_{\psi_2}.$$

Comment: I am familiar with this property (I am currently reading Vershynin's book, from which my question actually originated), but I am unsure that this is enough to show that the sum is still subgaussian... If we consider the norm $\|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \|$, don't we only know it is larger than the norm of the sum of centered random variables? And then we still don't know that the norm is finite, do we?

Comment: Ah, crap, you're talking about the inverse, of course. Oops. Lemme fix.

Comment: @LSK21 see the edited version. I've removed the background on $\psi_2$ norms since you're familiar.

Comment: Also, a simpler and more efficient argument from the centering property.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: One more quick question, should there be a $C$ in front of $ 2 \max (\|X_1\|, \|X_2\|) $ in the first half of the proof (where you prove the claim for $n=2$)? And is the second line in the first equation even necessary? I don't see where you use it later.

Comment: Yeah, sure, you can likely clean this up. As for the C, I don't think so - it's literally that if I set $K = 2 \max(\|X_1\|_{\psi_2}, \|X_2\|_{\psi_2}),$ then I get the bound $2$ on the product of expectations from Jensen's inequality. I think I put the $C$ in $Cn \max\|X_i\|_{\psi_2}$ because there might be a factor of two coming in from edge issues. Of course, I think the second argument is preferable instead, since that gives the stronger $O( \sum \|X_i\|_{\psi_2})$ bound.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that makes sense, I guess it's only in the first step of the iteration that the constant is so clean. And yes, the second one is definitely nicer :D